# Override AuthGuard to require login from a 3rd party

Tags: spartacus-storefront

What is the correct/best way of overriding the Spartacus AuthGuard with MsalGuard for example?

Should I just override it like a service or do I need to extend from it and change it?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the use case, extending makes sense if you want to reuse or build on top of the existing logic, which results in a better upgradability for most of the cases.

But in general, both should work OK, as you will end up with the new class that you'll have to provide as `AuthGuard`.

Answer (score 1):

Overriding the service would be cleanest because you will only have to provide an AuthService instead setting the MsalGuard on all your routes